# Разница между "вспоминать его" и "вспоминать о нем"

Tags: семантика

В чем разница между "вспоминать его" и "вспоминать о нем"? По-моему, "вспоминать его" значит сознательно вызывать у себя воспоминания о нем (предаваться воспоминаниям), а "вспоминать о нем" — это о непроизвольных вспышках памяти. Прав ли я?

Answer (score 2):

Не могу согласиться с такой трактовкой. Относительно глагола "вспоминать" словари управления, в общем случае, говорят следующее:

> **Вспомнить**
>       что и о чем.
>       1. что (восстановить в памяти содержание чего-л. во всем объеме). *Вспомнить забытое стихотворение. Вспомнить подробности встречи.*
>       2. о чем (восстановить в памяти какой-л. факт в общем виде). *Вспомнить о сказанном. Тут она вспомнила о письме и жадно бросилась его читать (Пушкин).*

В рассматриваемом случае "вспоминать его" также может означать, что вспоминается сам человек: внутренний мир, внешний вид, походка, черты лица и т.п. "Вспоминать о нём" будет относиться скорее к воспоминаниям событий, связанных с этим человеком.

В литературе часто можно встретить выражение-обещание "я буду вспоминать о тебе". Оно обычно не подразумевает "непроизвольные вспышки памяти".

Comment: Глагол совершенного вида "**вспомнить**" заметно отличается по употреблению от "**вспоминать**": "я вспомнил **его** - это он на джипе поджидал грабителей!". "Я вспомнил **о нём**, своём однокласснике: он ведь теперь классный кардиолог, мог бы помочь отцу". Глагол же несовершенного вида "вспоминать" (как в вопросе) в таких контекстах не употребляется.

Comment: Вспомнить грабителя - значит опознать его, вспомнить об однокласснике здесь - вспомнить о том, что он есть и мог бы помочь сейчас, а не об общем прошлом. Это как впомнить, что в кармане есть нужная вещь, которая решит проблему.

Comment: @Alex_ander Внимательно перечитал вопрос. Я не вижу там принципиальной привязки к сов. / несов. виду. Уверен, что автор вопроса мог то же самое сформулировать с глаголом "вспомнить" и суть вопроса от этого не изменилась бы.

Comment: По поводу "одноклассника" в Вашем предыдущем комментарии не могу согласиться, но спорить долго не хочу. Ваш вариант ответа тоже считаю допустимым, хотя думаю, что он относится только к отдельным, более редким, нюансам словоупотребления.

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО:

Вспоминать его = вспоминать его самого (образ)

Вспоминать о нём = вспоминать что-то о нём (что-то отдельное, частное). В частности, вспоминать что он вообще был/есть. Например, "я вспомнил о нём, когда подыскивал кандидатуру на эту должность".

Но разница между этими нюансами исчезающе мала, потому что вспоминая что-то о нём, мы часто вспомним и его самого, и наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

**Вспоминать его** - более характерно для людей, знавших человека с одной стороны (вспоминать его как блестящего оратора,  неподражаемого актёра, заядлого рыболова и т. п.).

**Вспоминать о нём** - типичнее для людей, близко знавших человека в разных его проявлениях. Либо это может делать группа людей, знавших человека с разных сторон, общавшихся с ним по разным поводам.

Comment: Хотелось бы получить более развернутый ответ.  Я думаю, вспомнить о нём — это вспомнить о том, что он существует (вслышка памяти). Про этом  "вспоминать о нем" — это повторяющееся действие "вспомнить о нем". А Вы, похоже,  с такой точкой зрения не согласны.  По-Вашему, это означает предаваться воспоминаниям, но широким, "о нем с разных сторон". Правильно ли я Вас понял?